# Window function POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, partition-by

| YEAR | sales |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1000 |
| 2022 | 1500 |
| 2023 | 2000 |

I want show 3rd column min sales with window function. But year=2022.

| YEAR | sales | min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1000 | 1500 |
| 2022 | 1500 | 1500 |
| 2023 | 2000 | 1500 |

I've tried the following query, but it didn't return the desired result:

```
select *,min(sales) over (partiton by year=2022) from table
```

Comment: It throws an error: "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "by""  look closely at the word before "by"  (and correct its spelling!)  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/g_F1rIzf which show the error)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with window functions:

```
select *
from "table",
(select min(sales) as minSale from "table" where year = 2022) x;
```

Comment: But this query returns a different result than the posted query with the correction made.... (Which is: `select *,min(sales) over (partition by year=2022) from mytable;`, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/wpuuzyJQ )

Comment: @Luuk, what do you mean? It returns the result as OP asked in your fiddle. If you meant the title, instead of minsales use "min".

Comment: Thank you for answer. That is perfect query.  But i wish i knew with window function is posible or not?

Comment: @ElvinMammadov, it is not a matter of possibility. I can write some nonsense code just to show it is possible.  If there were something to "window" then use window function. In your case it is not windowing, it is filtering.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: I tried to explain in a separate answer, which is an explanation of the output when the typo is corrected.

Comment: @Luuk, sorry I don\t get what you mean. In your first fiddle in reply to me, it shows that my code was correct and what OP wanted. This has nothing to do with window functions. If you meant keyword table than note that it is double quoted.

Answer (score 0):

When correcting the type in `partiton` to `partition`, you will get:

```
select 
   *,
   min(sales) over (partition by year=2022) 
from mytable
```

The results will be (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/oM28WrPs)):

| year | sales | min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2022 | 1500 | 1500 |
| 2023 | 2000 | 1000 |

This means the the sales value (or, actually, the smallest value for sales), in the year 2022 is 1500 (line 2).  And that the smallest value for sales in the years that are nor equal to 2022 is 1000 (lines 1 and 3)

P.S. I also renamed `table` to `mytable`, because `table` is a reserved word. One ***should*** avoid using a reserved word in an SQL query, more info: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reserved+word+sql+table+